# Multer new version, undefined uploaded images file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When i uploaded an Image with multer middle ware, i got undefined file image. In other words, i cannot get the name or the file extension from the file i uploaded. I don't know if it is the error from multer.
Here is my js file:

```js
var express = require('express');
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({dest:'uploads/'});
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/register', upload.single('profile'), function(req, res, next){


if(req.file){
    console.log("Uploading files");
    //get all Properties of the files object

   var profileImageOriginalName = req.file.profile.originalname;
    var profileImageName = req.file.profile.name;
    var profileImageMime = req.file.profile.mimetype;
    var profileImagePath = req.file.profile.path;
    var profileImageExt = req.file.profile.extension;
    var profileImageSize = req.file.profile.size;
}
```

And here is my html form file in **jade format**:

```html
input.form-control(name = 'profile', type = 'file')
```

The Type Error : **Cannot Read the originalname of undefined**

Comment: form enctype is"multipart/form-data" ?

Comment: yes it is, that is the requirement for multipart form to upload

Answer (score 0):

For `.single()`, the `req.file` contains the file properties directly (e.g. `req.file.originalname`).